# Chemical Reagent Test sensitive at low concentrations

Tags: analytical-chemistry

Would there be a spot test/tests that can detect either/both of the following molecules at low concentrations?

The likely concentrations are in the $10{-}\pu{50 mg/L}$ range in an aqueous solution. Ideally, I'd want something that does not need an exotic/expensive instrument.  e.g. a color change or precipitation or conductivity/pH change.

[image]

[image]

The background interference: The sample is *Terrific Broth* which has the following composition:

$\pu{12 g}$ Bacto tryptone
$\pu{24 g}$ Bacto yeast extract
$\pu{4 mL}$ Glycerol
$\pu{100 mL}\ \pu{0.17M}\ \ce{KH2PO4}$ and $\pu{0.72M}\ \ce{K2HPO4}$, sterile, to be prepared separately from the tryptone, yeast extract, and glycerol solution.

Comment: Any sort of such a spot test would depend heavily on what else might be in the solution. So what other "stuff" could be in the water? I wouldn't expect either of those molecules to be very water soluble.

Comment: Thanks @MaxW I've added info about what else could be in the sample. And yes you are right these are not very water soluble although at the low conc. I am expecting they very well might be.  This is a conc. of less that 0.01%.

Comment: In  any case, I want to brainstorm possible test options. At which point I can test them out on control samples of the broth to see what reaction I get.

Comment: >Bacto yeast extract || yeah, forget about any meaningful spectroscopy for such low concentrations with this unholy mix in the media. Theoretically speaking, a highly selective molecular recognition agent such as specifically tailored antibody may work, but the R&D required would be quite costly, so unless your needs do not exceed thousands of samples, it is not even worth considering. Other than thatn, GS/GSMS is your best bet.

Comment: @permeakra Thanks for the insight. That's what I feared. GCMS works well, just that it is slow as number of samples scale.

Comment: @permeakra One question motivated by the GCMS idea. Typically we extract into 1:2 Hexane or Ethyl Acetate & then inject into the GCMS. Would that pre-extraction make spectroscopy any more feasible? I suppose most of the unholy mix from the media won't get extracted into the organic phase. The GCMS does come out clean. Thoughts?

Comment: @curious_cat Highly doubt it. Living matter contains a lot of minor hydrophobic compounds plus lipids that should extract easily by the mixture, and IC and UV specters usually have wide peaks. Furthermore, some of said compounds are so heavy that they may irreversibly contaminate GC column, some of them (like metal-porphyrins ) leaving something that cannot even be burnt out completely. So, I would look for liquid chromatography solution and filtered the extract using some extremely fine filter before analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the pure compounds on hand?  If you do, the two target compounds can be crudely isolated by extracting the broth with diethyl ether, concentrating it down, and spotting on SiO2 TLC plate. Compare RF with that of the pure compounds. 
Alternatively, the same general extraction methodology could prepare a sample for GC-MS or crude NMR, if such instrumentation is available